# Grab object values during runtime for creating Mock objects required for writing Unit Test

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

Consider the below class which needs to be tested,

```
class ToBeTested
{
  Employee _e;
  public ToBeTested(Employee e)
  {
  _e = e;
  }

  void Process()
  {
  // Do something with _e
  }
}

    [TestClass]
    class ToBeTestedTest
    {
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestProcessMethod()
    {
      Employee e = // Initialise it with some test value..
      ToBeTested tbt = new ToBeTested(e);
      tbt.Process();

      //Assert to Verify the test results...  
    }
```

The Problem is `Employee` can really be a very complex type with properties in it which themselves can be objects of more classes. It becomes difficult to initialise Employee with Mock Values and generate a testable object.

While debugging I can set a breakpoint and see what `Employee` object in `ToBeTested` contains. Is there a way by which I can grab all the values from this object as is available during runtime and use it in my test method?

Answer (score 8):

You can use **[Object Exporter](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c6a21c68-f815-4895-999f-cd0885d8774f)**. Its an extension for Visual studio which will generate C# initialization code from any object in your debugging windows. You can use this generated code in your unit test initialization.

[image]

Comment: thanks @CarbineCoder. But unfortunately it did not work for me. The C# Object generation did not output the class properly. The private fields were still there although I checked the "Exclude private fields.." checkbox :(

Comment: Hey @user1928158, this might be a bit late but could you post this issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/OmarElabd/ObjectExporter/issues)? I try and fix any issues that come up. I haven't seen any issues with private fields, but do let me know and hopefully I can resolve the issue.

Comment: @OmarElabd Great job! I don't regularly use it, but its a really good extension.

Answer (score 3):

The mentioned Visual Studio Extension (OmarElabd/ObjectExporter) was a good idea, but I needed to generate C# code from in-memory objects **at runtime**, during unit test execution. This is what evolved from the original problem: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ObjectDumper.NET/

ObjectDumper.Dump(obj, DumpStyle.CSharp); returns C# initializer code from a variable. Please let me know if you find issues, you might want to report them on github.